# Magnitude difference between companion in binary from mass difference in binaries

Tags: binary-star, estimate

Is there any hypothesis on how to estimate the difference between visual magnitudes of binary components based on their masses? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Are they both main sequence stars?

With main sequence stars there is a relationship between spectral class, mass, and luminosity.

For example, you can go to [Wikipedia's page on spectral classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_classification#Spectral_types)

And you can click on the links to each spectral class.  Each spectral class is divided into 10 subclasses, and each article should have a chart showing the mass, luminosity, radius, etc. of each subclass within the class.

If one or both of hte stars are not main sequence stars, then they can be at several different stages in which a star with a particular mass can have very different luminosity.  Thus the luminosities of non main sequence stars can not be predicted merely from their masses.

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes, they are main-sequence stars.

Comment: How to get the difference of components' visual magnitudes when luminosities will be known, please?